# Adding DIV Content to Listbox option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have been working on a script to pull the *STRONG* element of .*this* *DIV* with .append applied to the *DIV* and plop that into a listbox.option.  The code I have so far succeeds in bringing the elements into the list but it starts to get a little messy in the *DIV* when I append the element because it already contains a comma in the paragraph. It also adds to the other *STRONG* tag in another *DIV*.  All I am really looking for is just simple way to pull the contents of DIVa.STRONG element with a ", " into the listbox.  I would be very grateful if someone has a solution or can help me understand what needs to happen.  Thank you all.

Please refer to my jsfiddle [Example Site:](http://jsfiddle.net/timmaynet/MTpH2/8/)

or

Html:

```
<div id="div1"><span name="#anchor" style="color: black;">Blah Blah <strong>A</strong> and <strong>B</strong> manufactured by <strong>C</strong> blah blah.</span><a href="#">delete</a></div><div id="div2"><strong>Test</strong></div>

    <form>
        <select id="mySelect" size="8">
        <option>Apple</option>
        <option>Pear</option>
        <option>Banana</option>
        <option>Orange</option>
        </select>
    </form>
    <br /><div>
    <p>Test words in paragraph</p>
```

Javascript:

```
$("a").click(function(e){

  $div = $(this).parent("div");

  id = $div.attr("id");

  $( "strong" ).append( ", ");

  text = $div.find("strong").text();

     var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
     var option = document.createElement("option");
       option.text = text.substr(0,(text.length -2));
         x.add(option,x[0]);

 e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

Comment: Can  you just say what you want to get as the result? It would be much better if your answer will be formatted with \` (inline code) tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MTpH2/21/)?

Code above do this:

- find each strong element in `#div1` and get its value append this
- value to `#mySelect`

jQuery code:

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    var arr = [];
    $("#div1 strong").each(function() {
        arr.push($(this).html());
    });
    $("#mySelect").append("<option>"+arr.join(', ')+"</option>");
});
```

**Note:**

You mixing up jQuery code and js code. It is not good practise. You are already using jQuery, so use it for all things what you need. You haven't to mix it up with js code.

Comment: Almost perfect! I will need all the strong elements in one line with the a comma and space. However, I do like the way you approached it.  I just will need the strong elements in one row for this example.

Comment: Great!  I really want to be your friend!